# How to format android EditText after paste?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, I need to know how do I format android EditText after pasting a number to it?

I have following XML in my XML file to EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_number_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="14"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:text="Your Number: "
    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp" />
```

For instance, after I paste "23989723412" to EditText, it should format it automatically to "129.897.234-12".

I did some research, however, I am not sure what event triggers when a number is pasted in EditText, but it may have to do something with `afterTextChanged` but I don't know how to do it for this purpose in Java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the logic for 129. 897 etc... Can you explain your requirements ?

Comment: What is the relation between the 1st 3 digits in BEFORE (239) & the corresponding ones in AFTER (129)?

Comment: Those are 3 digits number format for storing user ID

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a dot every 3 numbers for improved reading.

> e.x. 1290030022 = 1.290.030.022

Feel free to use the code snippet below in your `Activity.java`:

```
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.myeditText);
        try {
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();

            Integer value = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            String format = decimalFormat.format(value);
            System.out.println("Result:" + format);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I read your comment & I appreciate the answer, if you see the question the format I was looking for was 'xxx.xxx.xxx-xx'. So, there is a dash at the end. However, I solved it. Also I wanted to know how to trigger an event that fires on paste.

Comment: Alright. Glad you solved it! I thought that -xx was a tipping mistakes because the "-" is located next to the "."

Comment: Thank You For your Help & Comment, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! That's what the community is made for. Cheers and happy Coding!